# comparison of datagridview cell values

Tags: c#

I am trying to compare values of two datagridview cells:

```
if (kk.BoringData.Rows[rows].Cells[0].Value != kk.BoringData.Rows[rows - 1].Cells[0].Value)
{
...
}
```

Both cell values are "B-1", but it returns true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property is of type `object`, meaning the [`!=` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz250sf.aspx) tests for [*reference equality*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183752.aspx) (whether the two objects occupy the same location in memory). To compare the strings by their *values* you can try using [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.equals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (!kk.BoringData.Rows[rows].Cells[0].Value.Equals(kk.BoringData.Rows[rows - 1].Cells[0].Value))
```

Or convert them to strings before testing them like this:

```
if (kk.BoringData.Rows[rows].Cells[0].Value.ToString() != kk.BoringData.Rows[rows - 1].Cells[0].Value.ToString())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting the Value property to the apropriate type e.g. string, int, double and then perform the comparison.

Google for C# unboxing

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to reiterate a bit here as I had a similar problem and found the explanation above regarding 'Reference Equality', but adding this code for a slightly different viewpoint.

```
if (e.ColumnIndex == Column1.index && e.RowIndex > 0)
   {
      //if (DataGridView[Column1.Index, e.RowIndex].Value == DataGridView[Column1.Index, e.RowIndex - 1].Value)  //Always false. Reference Equality
      //if ((string)DataGridView[Column1.Index, e.RowIndex].Value == (string)DataGridView[Column1.Index, e.RowIndex - 1].Value) //True or False as expected. Value Equality
      if (DataGridView[Column1.Index, e.RowIndex].Value.Equals(DataGridView[Column1.Index, e.RowIndex - 1].Value)) //True or False as expected. Value Equality
      {//Do Stuff
      }
      else
      {//Do other stuff
      }
   }
```